# dotcloud - google apps email configuration

Tags: email, dotcloud

I've checked out dotcloud, it seems quite promising. I use google apps for my email, so it is very important for me to be able to set up my MX records to point to gmail servers.
I want to know if this is possible with dotcloud, I tried searching for this but didn't find any references.

Could someone who has used dotcloud tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At dotCloud, we don't take control of your DNS so you are welcome to send your mail wherever you want. We have plenty of users who use gmail for email and have their sites and applications hosted on dotCloud. If you have any additional questions, feel free to shoot us an email at support@dotcloud.com - we'd be more than happy to answer any questions you might have.

Best Regards,

Charles H

Full-disclosure: If it's not immediately obvious, I work at dotCloud.

Comment: That's good to know, but if I want my site to be hosted on a custom domain, then do I not need to set the DNS to dotcloud dns servers?

Comment: For DNS, you would set a CNAME for your custom domain (described in our docs) and then for Gmail, you would set various MX records (described in gmail's docs). If you need any more in-depth information, feel free to write us at our support email address!